# bash: filenames as parameter, perform action in cycle

Tags: bash, for-loop, parameters

My current script goes like:

```
#!/bin/bash

victims=*asci*

for f in $victims ; do
awk /some blah blah here/  ;done
```

so basically takes all files containing *ascii* in their name and performs an action on them.

I wanted, however, the filenames be entered as a parameter. Like:
`bash myscript.sh *log*` for example.

When using

```
#!/bin/bash

victims="$1"

for f in $victims ; do
awk /some blah blah here/  ;done
```

it doesnt do what expected. Performs only on the first file (as far as I remember).

May I ask for a help? Want the script to perform a function over a bunch of files that contain the parameter in their filename. Im not very experienced in bash, honestly. Thanks, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

If you're just calling `awk` then you don't even need the `for` loop. Just pass it all of the file names at once.

```
awk '/whatever/' "$@"
```

If you do want to loop over all the command-line arguments, write:

```
for f in "$@"; do
    ...
done
```

Or, since `in "$@"` is implied:

```
for f; do
    ...
done
```

If you want to store them in an intermediate variable, you need to use an array:

```
victims=("$@")

for f in "${victims[@]}"; do
    ...
done
```

Also, you should avoid explicitly invoking `bash`. Run the script directly so it can use whatever shell's listed in its shebang line.

```
bash myscript.sh *log*
./myscript.sh *log*
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch out how you call your script.   Suppose your script myscript.sh is simply

```
victims="$1"
echo "$victims"
```

and your cwd contains  files  a.log, another.log and logmore.txt.

Then, executing

```
myscript.sh *log*
```

Wil result in simply

```
a.log
```

because "`*log*`" is interpreted by the shell before calling myscript.sh.  In fact, you're executing

```
myscript.sh a.log another.log logmore.txt
```

and your script only handles the first parameter.  Also very funny is, when your cwd contains no file with "log" in its name, your script will result in:

```
*log*
```

So, your call should be:

```
myscript.sh "*log*"
```

and your script should handle the fact that its input may be a regulare expression iso. an existing filename.